# Cant remove Subview of view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I can't seem to achieve removing a subview of a subview of a view.
Its like this:

`[self.view addSubview:myView];`

`[myView addSubview:overlay];`

My .h :

```
@interface

    UIView *myView;
    IBOutlet Overlay *overlay;
...
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet Overlay *overlay;
...
```

.m :

```
-(void) method {   
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420.0f,0.0f,604.0f,768.0f)];
    [self.view addSubview:myView]; 

    Overlay *o = [[Overlay alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(000.0f,000.0f,604.0f,768.0f)];
    [myView addSubview:o];
}
```

I tried `[myView removeFromSuperview]` and`[myView removeFromSuperview]`inside the `void method`, it works.
What I needed is to make it work outside or into a different `void` but what Im doing is not working.

Note:

It says when I alloc myView `"Local declaration of 'myView' hides instance variable."`

Comment: I hope you use more descriptive names in your *real code* beyond `method` and `myView`.

Comment: Does that have an effect? Is naming probably what's wrong in my code? I'll try changing them. Thanks @MichaelDautermann :)

Comment: no... naming is ***not*** what's wrong with your code (and that's why what I was saying was a comment and suggestion, not an official answer).  Method and variable names should be more descriptive in code, always.  Makes things more readable for you later on.  For your problem right now, Evan's answer is likely the correct one for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ill improve my variable naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `UIView *myView = (init code)` with `self.myView = (init code)`. You are redeclaring `myView` as a local variable that already has scope within your class, since you made it a property. (The same thing goes for `Overlay`.)

Then, you can use `[self.myView removeFromSuperview]` anywhere in this class.

Comment: just do remember to set `self.myView = nil;` to release memory in `dealloc` if you are not using ARC.